# Latest entry of group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: items and prices

prices is a collection of prices at different timestamps for an item (in this case 24)

[image: prices]

items contains descriptions for all items

[image: items]

I now want to query name, sell price, buy price, offer count, demand count and both ids for the latest price for each item.

My current solution

```
SELECT items.id as id, items.icon as icon, items.name AS name, prices.sell as sell, prices.buy as buy, prices.demand as demand, prices.offer as offer, prices.timestamp as timestamp
FROM items JOIN prices ON prices.itemID = items.id
WHERE buy < 100000
  AND sell < 100000
  AND demand > 10000
  AND offer > 10000
  AND timestamp IN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM prices AS p WHERE p.id = prices.id)
GROUP BY items.id
ORDER BY sell / buy
DESC LIMIT 25
```

doesn't work at all (the rows seem to be random, but they are surely not the latest ones).

Comment: Any non-calculated columns in SELECT should be in GROUP BY as well, otherwise the result might not be what you expected

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my crappy pictures I realized the solution was just in front of me. Instead of needing to group I can just use the items.lastupdate for selecting the proper row of prices

```
FROM items JOIN prices ON prices.itemID = items.id AND prices.timestamp = items.lastupdate
```

Comment: there might be a difference in the timestamp value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.id, i.icon, i.name, p.sell, p.buy, p.demand, p.offer, p.`timestamp`
FROM items i, prices p, (
    SELECT itemID, max(`timestamp`) max_ts
    FROM prices
    WHERE buy < 100000 AND sell < 100000 AND demand > 10000 AND offer > 10000
    GROUP BY 1
) as last_p
WHERE i.id = p.itemID
AND p.itemID = last_p.itemID AND p.`timestamp` = last_p.max_ts
```

The result might be different if you put the following WHERE inside or outside the sub-query, it is up to your actual situation:

```
WHERE buy < 100000 AND sell < 100000 AND demand > 10000 AND offer > 10000
```